# Show one same template for two category

Tags: categories

I want to show `gallery.php` template for category. I am currently using `category-15.php` and `category-19.php` technique.

I want to redirect category 15 and 19 to `gallery.php` instead (one template for two category). And I want to use a simpler technique. It can be by using `functions.php`.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in many ways.

Two solutions I recommend are:

### 1. Editing category template

Just edit your `category.php` template and put if statement in there:

```
if ( is_category( array(15, 19) ) )
  get_template_part('category-15-19');
else
  get_template_part('category-all')
```

Then just put code for category 15 and 19 into `category-15-19.php` file and code for other categories into `category-all.php` file.

### 2. Using [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) hook

Add filter to `template_include` hook. It should return template name that should be displayed by WordPress.

```
function my_categories_template($template_name) {
   if ( is_category( array(15, 19) ) )
       return 'category-15-19.php';
   return $template_name;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_categories_template' );
```

Comment: Thank you but it show the blank page while loading category 15 and 19 pages. Can you re-check the code(the second one).

Comment: Which solution did you use?

Comment: i am using second one